# Wrong type of object after subscribe in RxJS

Tags: angular, http, typescript, firebase

I have an Angular 4 app.

I have a service that fetch data from Firebase database by API URL:

```
import { Product } from './../models/product';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppSettings } from '../app-settings';

@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {

  products = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(AppSettings.DB_API_ENDPOINT + '/products.json',);
  }
}
```

And the component that displays that data:

```
import { Product } from './../../models/product';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductsService } from '../../services/products.service';
import { CategoriesService } from '../../services/categories.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'products-list',
  templateUrl: './products-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products-list.component.scss']
})
export class ProductsListComponent implements OnInit {

  products: Product[];
  numberOfProducts: number;
  page: number;

  constructor(private productsService: ProductsService, private categoriesService: CategoriesService) {
    this.page = 1;
    this.numberOfProducts = 0;
    this.products = [];
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      console.log(products[0].getId());
      this.products.push(products[0] as Product);
      this.numberOfProducts = this.products.reduce((prev, el) => {
        return prev + el.qtyAvailable;
      }, 0);
    });
  }

  qtyChange(qty: number) {
    this.numberOfProducts -= qty;
  }

}
```

And the model `Product`:

```
export class Product {
    $key: string;
    qty: number;
    isSoldOut: boolean;

    constructor(
        private id: number,
        private name: string,
        private description: string,
        public qtyAvailable: number,
        private price: number,
        private image: string,
        public category: string
    ) {
        this.isSoldOut = false;
        this.qty = 0;
    }

    isAvailable() {
        return !this.isSoldOut;
    }

    getImageUrl() {
        return '/assets/images/products/' + this.image;
    }

    public getId(): number {
        return this.id;
    }

    getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

In the view of that component I use `product.isAvailable()` method from the model `Product`. I get th error message in console `ERROR TypeError: _co.product.isAvailable is not a function`. But when I type `products[0].id` in the service I get the error message while compile, that `id` is a private of `Product`. The list of producsts is displayed and paginated but without data, because of this error message.

Comment: `as Product` **does not** do any casting or conversion, it's just a hint to the compiler. If you need an instance of that class, you need to create one yourself; the JSON data will just be a simple object with the properties set.

Comment: Yes, I know. I have tried to create the Product object in the service `subscribe` method but I get the compiler error that the field is private (so it indicates that TypeScript treats it like Product type) or when I try to use i.e. `getId()` I get error in JS console that `getId()` is not a function (so JS treats it like no `Product` type). And I am stuck right now.

Comment: If you know, and you've tried it, *why not show a [mcve] **of that attempt**?*

Comment: I suppose that Angular `get<Product[]>()` method with type specified inside `<>` convert the type for me automatically and I will have the methods available when I subscribe to the response. It is wired for me. But as I suppose now the type in `<>` has no meaning for runtime only for compile. I have fileds available but no methods from the `Product` class.

Comment: *"the type in `<>` has no meaning for runtime only for compile"* - correct, TypeScript is **purely at compile time**. It compiles to JavaScript, which doesn't have types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a better way to organize this in Rxjs. This will handle everything inside your service mrthod:

```
getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(AppSettings.DB_API_ENDPOINT + '/products.json',)
      .switchMap(res => res); // make the retrieved list an Observable itself
      .map(product => new Product(product.name // etc)) // map every json object to an instance of your class
      .toArray(); // when the list is over, the Observable created from the json list will complete, and all of the emitted values will be stored in an array
}
```

For reference see these links: [switchMap operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap), [toArray operator](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-toArray)

This way is more cleaner, readable and in a more *reactive* style

Comment: Thanks! I wrote something like this earlier and it works fine.
`getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> { return this.http.get<any[]>(AppSettings.DB_API_ENDPOINT + '/products.json').map(res => { return res.map(p => new Product(p.id, p.name, p.description, p.qty, p.price, p.image, p.category)); }); `
But your solution is more readable.

Answer (score -1):

I resolved my problem by using array syntax of JavaScript objects, to create the object of type `Product` inside `subscribe` method:

```
this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(products => {
      this.products = products.map(p => new Product(p['id'], p['name'], p['description'], p['qtyAvailable'], p['price'],p['image'], p['category']));
      this.numberOfProducts = this.products.reduce((prev, el) => {
        return prev + el.qtyAvailable;
      }, 0);
    });
```

But still, I think it is redundant. Angular should automatically convert the type to `Product[]`, should it?.

Comment: 1. The typing is TypeScript functionality, not Angular specific. 2. No, it shouldn't.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @jonrsharpe. I have the next question. Is it possible to do this creation of `Product[]` inside the `getProducts` method of `ProductService` to not repeat the code every time I use `this.productsService.getProducts().subscribe(....)` ? I would like to do the conversion only in `ProductService` leaving the code asynchronous.

Comment: Yes, of course it is. I'd suggest you spend some time thinking about it.

Comment: Is it a right solution for that:
`getProducts(): Observable<Product[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(AppSettings.DB_API_ENDPOINT + '/products.json').map(res => {
      return res.map(p => new Product(p.id, p.name, p.description, p.qty, p.price, p.image, p.category));
    });
  }`

Comment: Why are you asking me? Did you try it? Do the tests pass? You should be able to answer your own question there.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and it works. But I am not sure if it is the best so I ask you. Very sorry for disturbing you. Thanks again!