# Domain model does not work - Angular 6 & core.net 2 REST with Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, visual-studio-2017

I have following problem...

**Environment:**
IDE: VS2017
Project: Angular 6 with .Net core 2 configured with webpack
Dev-System: Win-Server 2012 R2
Testing: VS2017 Debug mode with IIS Express and Chrome

**Versions & Configuration:**

*package.json:*

- In-Scripts config: "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --progress -- profile --mode=development",
- "@angular/cdk": "^6.3.3",
- "@angular/cli": "^6.0.8",
- "@angular/core": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/forms": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/http": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/router": "^6.0.9",
- "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
- "@ngtools/webpack": "^6.0.8",
- "@types/alertify": "^0.3.30",
- "alertify-js": "^0.3.12",
- "angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",
- "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
- "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
- "core-js": "^2.4.1",
- "jquery": "^3.3.1",
- "jquery-validation": "^1.17.0",
- "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.10",
- "moment": "^2.22.2",
- "ng-pick-datetime": "^6.0.10",
- "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
- "ngx-bootstrap": "^3.0.1",
- "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
- "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
- "rxjs": "^6.2.1",
- "systemjs": "0.19.40",
- "text-mask-addons": "^3.7.2",
- "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
- "webpack-merge": "^4.1.3",
- "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
- "@angular/animations": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/common": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.9",
- "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.9",
- "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.36",
- "@types/jquery": "^3.3.4",
- "@types/node": "^10.5.2",
- "angular2-router-loader": "^0.3.5",
- "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
- "awesome-typescript-loader": "^5.2.0",
- "del": "latest",
- "gulp": "^3.9.1",
- "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
- "path": "latest",
- "typescript": "^2.7.2",
- "webpack": "^4.16.0",
- "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"

*webpack.config.js:*

```
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    const merge = require('webpack-merge');
    const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;
    const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;

        module.exports = (env) => {
        // Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
        const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
        const sharedConfig = {
            stats: { modules: false },
            context: __dirname,
            resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
            output: {
                filename: '[name].js',
                publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
            },
            module: {
                rules: [
                    { test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true', 'angular2-template-loader', 'angular2-router-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack' },
                    { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
                    { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' ] },
                    { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }
                ]
            },
            plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()/*, new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: "jquery",
                jQuery: "jquery"
            })*/]
        };

        // Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
        const clientBundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';
        const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
            entry: { 'main-client': './app/boot.browser.ts' },
            output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
            plugins: [
                new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                    context: __dirname,
                    manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
                })
            ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
                // Plugins that apply in development builds only
                new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                    filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                    moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(clientBundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
                })
            ] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
                new AotPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, './app/app.module#AppModule'),
                    exclude: ['./**/*.server.ts']
                })
            ])
        });

        // Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
        const serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
            resolve: { mainFields: ['main'] },
            entry: { 'main-server': './app/boot.server.ts' },
            plugins: [
                new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                    context: __dirname,
                    manifest: require('./app/dist/vendor-manifest.json'),
                    sourceType: 'commonjs2',
                    name: './vendor'
                })
            ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
                // Plugins that apply in production builds only
                new AotPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: path.join(__dirname, './app/app.module#AppModule'),
                    exclude: ['./**/*.browser.ts']
                })
            ]),
            output: {
                libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
                path: path.join(__dirname, './app/dist')
            },
            target: 'node',
            devtool: 'inline-source-map'
        });

        return [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
        };
```

**Relevant code (snippets):**

*my-service-method:*

```
    getTimeTracking(userId: string, year: number, month: number): Promise<TimeTracking> {
        const url = `${this.timeTrackingsUrl}/${userId}/${year}/${month}`;
        return this.clientHttp.get<TimeTracking>(url)
            .toPromise<TimeTracking>()
            .catch(this.handleError.bind(this));
    }
```

*Domain model class (here: TimeTracking):*

```
export class TimeTracking implements Serializable<TimeTracking> {
    id: string = '';
    userId: string = '';
    month: Date = new Date(0);
    timeTrackingEntries: TimeTrackingEntry[] = [];
    status: TimeTrackingStatus = 0;

    [... more code ...]

    isReadOnly(): boolean {
        return (this.status == TimeTrackingStatus.Saved);
    }

    [... more code ...]
}
```

*My-Component:*

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id.toString(),
    templateUrl: 'time-tracking.component.html'})
export class TimeTrackingComponent implements OnInit {

    timeTracking: TimeTracking | undefined;

    [... more code ...]

    this.timeTrackingService.getTimeTracking(this.currentUser.userid, this.selectedMonthDate.getFullYear(), this.selectedMonthDate.getMonth() + 1)
        .then(timeTracking => {
            if (this.timeTrackingForm) {
                this.timeTrackingForm.reset();
            }
            this.timeTracking = timeTracking;
        })

    [... more code ...]
}
```

*And here my html for this component:*

```
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!timeTrackingForm.form.valid || (timeTracking?.isReadOnly())" (click)="save()">Save</button>
```

**My problem:**

Everything will compile, webpack has also no problems to build. When I start debugging with VS2017 - IIS Express, Server will be started and Chrome is opened.
I navigate to relevant page and with network overview I can say API call succeeded and data were transfered. But I get this error in Chrome console in developer options:

***ERROR TypeError: _co.timeTracking.isReadOnly is not a function***

[image: API-Call successfully]

And if I set a breakpoint, I determine that the data object is NOT mapped in my domain model object:

[image: API data is of type object!]

**Questions:**

1. Why is my data not mapped to the specified domain model object with
   "get()"?
2. Did I something wrong?
3. How can I achieve that my domain model is used (where the data
   object has functions in it)?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: `.get<TimeTracking>` **does not** invoke any casting or conversion. TypeScript is purely a *compile time* language, it does not exist at runtime so can't do any of that. If you want to convert the JSON payload objects you're receiving into instances of classes, you must do that explicitly yourself. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/51229861/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/46717706/3001761, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47368759/3001761, ...

Comment: Thank you very much @jonrsharpe So I assume that there are many misunderstanding tutorials in the net. This was not clear to me. But to add a explicit mapping is not difficult. *ThumbsUp*

Comment: If you find a tutorial that claims the http client, or type hints generally, *will* invoke explicit conversion, you should report that inaccuracy to its author.